# WebView with ssl in api 17 (Jelly Bean 4.2)

Tags: android, ssl, webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

i have a webview that need access to site with ssl certificate, and my question is **if i can access to this site on devices with api 17?** i read on the web that we can override the "onReceivedSslError" like this:

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webivew);
webview .setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

@Override
public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    handler.proceed();
}
});
```

but i always get the answer in the methods "onReceivedError" and the description is : "Couldn't establish a secure connection".

update : the website i'm trying to access is using **TLS 1.2 protocol** (AWS server)

Any suggestions?

Comment: post complete error log

Comment: errorCode -11,
description : Couldn't establish a secure connection,
failingUrl :

Comment: below 4.4 (KitKat) is not supprt ssl -tsl